# job won't go out of "pending" state

Tags: google-bigquery

one of our jobs is holding up the queue because it's not going out of "pending" state for 5 days. Job id is apps_prod_orgsite_terracotta_lan_bigquery-data-2013-01-23_11-08-11-194_csv_gz

```
$ ./bq show -j apps_prod_orgsite_terracotta_lan_bigquery-data-2013-01-23_11-08-11-194_csv_gz
Job phonehomedata:apps_prod_orgsite_terracotta_lan_bigquery-data-2013-01-23_11-08-11-194_csv_gz
  Job Type    State    Start Time   Duration   Bytes Processed  
 ---------- --------- ------------ ---------- ----------------- 
  load       PENDING
```

Is this supposed to happen? It should at least fail or timeout?

EDITED: correct jobid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there was a glitch in our job processing service on that affected 22 jobs that started on 1/23 between 10:55 and 11:30 AM PST. We're investigating the issue. Can you re-run the job?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I could rerun the job tomorrow. Due to the backlog of jobs during the last 5 days, we've hit the quota for today unfortunately.

Comment: The quota should be pretty high for imports -- 1k imports per table per day or 10k per project per day. Are you doing more than that?

Comment: We hit 1K imports per table limit today while trying to processing the 5 days backlog. We used to collect and upload data every 5 minutes so that is a lot of files to upload. We have since made our process to upload every hour instead.

Answer (score 0):

actually the problematic job id is "apps_prod_orgsite_terracotta_lan_bigquery-data-2013-01-23_11-08-11-194_csv_gz" I think